# How to build an "editor" in Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, user-interface

I am looking for some very general advice on how to implement editing in Cocoa. Not for text, but shapes, pictures, etc. Basically I want to implement objects on a drawing board that the user can e.g. drag around, assign new content, resize, ... Similar to almost any graphical editor like Keynote, Pages, Drawing programs.

I think there is no solution built into Cocoa, and I am not aware of any other implementation (besides CGDrawKit, but that's somehow only for drawing). What would be your advice on how to implement this?

Comment: I'd find an application with source code that does this in a language that I understand; use that to explore the architecture of such a solution and the use that knowledge to develop my own solution.

Comment: Don't write off GCDrawKit. It's probably a good starting point to save you effort.

Comment: SO is not really the site for "general advice". Please see [the FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#ask) and try to edit this to address a specific, _concrete_ problem you are facing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at the Sketch sample code, which is installed in /Developer/Examples/.